# Flask query not working with table

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I have this script that I import into the route:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("c:/DB/tvldb.db")  

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''SELECT code, type, issue, item_type, list_code FROM Issues''')

datarows = cursor.fetchall()

conn.close()
```

That works fine when I print it.

Here is the route:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import db_issues

app = Flask(__name__)

datarows = db_issues.datarows

@app.route('/issues')
def issues():
   return render_template('leftside.html', datarows=datarows)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is the template:

```
<h2 id="pageTitle"> Missing Items</h2>
<table style="width:85%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Issue</th>
        <th>Entry Type</th>
        <th>List Code</th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in datarows %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ code }}</td>
            <td>{{ type }}</td>
            <td>{{ Issue }}</td>
            <td>{{ item_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ list_code }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table><br><br>
{% endblock %}
```

The table shows ok but no data is filled in. I been trying all day to do this simple thing and having no luck. According to all the tutorials and stackoverflow answers I checked, this should be correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write your table like this (not tested yet):

```
{% for row in datarows %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row['code'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row['type'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row['issue'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row['item_type'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ row['list_code'] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look more closely at `datarows`. It'll be a list of tuples, not a dictionary. That is, there no names to associate with each 'column', so attempts to reference in the template, say, `row.code` are going to fail, because `row` is a tuple.

You could, with a bit of work, turn the rows into dictionaries, by matching up the slots in each tuple with names found in `cursor.description`. There's an example of how to do that using `row_factory` in the [sqlite3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory).

Answer (score -1):

Always debug the variable that you are passing to the rendered page this will let you know that whether the data are inside the index or not

```
print(variable)
```

Using this you will be confirmed that what data you have to parse to the template page

Comment: I did that in a separate script